# Why does postfix failed and prefix work fine when pass an iterator as argument and recurse it at tail position?

Tags: c++, recursion, prefix, postfix-mta

I come across this problem accidentally.

I have thought google can solve it surely, but after searching multiple keywords, I still can't find answers, which confused me a lot.

When I use prefix at tail position, codes works fine:

```
template<class ContinerIterator, class F>
constexpr auto fun(ContinerIterator IteratorBegin, ContinerIterator IteratorEnd, F f)
{
    switch (IteratorBegin == IteratorEnd)
    {
    case true: return;
    case false: f(*IteratorBegin);
    }
    return fun(++IteratorBegin, IteratorEnd, f);
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    fun(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [](auto &a)->auto{a *= 2; });
    for (auto v : a)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

---

Howerer, if I use postfix, `IteratorBegin` nerve arrives `iteratorEnd` and goes far and far away, so segmentfault.

```
template<class ContinerIterator, class F>
constexpr auto fun(ContinerIterator IteratorBegin, ContinerIterator IteratorEnd, F f)
{
    switch (IteratorBegin == IteratorEnd)
    {
    case true: return;
    case false: f(*IteratorBegin);
    }
    return fun(IteratorBegin++, IteratorEnd, f);
}
void test()
{

}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    fun(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [](auto &a)->auto{a *= 2; });
    for (auto v : a)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried on MSVC, G++, Clang, all fails. 
Here is gcc's error list:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here is Clang's:

> Error occurred (timeout). Try again later.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If postfix is implemented according to the usual semantics, it should be obvious.

Comment: It’s unusual to see a switch statement used that way. I’d just use a regular old if/else for that.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have tried debug, like step into function, then find IteratorBeginner keep increasing.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks! I am to uncareful and didn't notice the iterator itself is the still the same address, what varies is its value. Maybe it is the result of staying up late many days, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement

```
return fun(IteratorBegin++, IteratorEnd, f);
```

with some exceptions can be considered like

```
fun(IteratorBegin, IteratorEnd, f);
++IteratorBegin;
return;
```

So the function is always called with the same value of `IteratorBegin`.

From the C++ Standard (5.2.6 Increment and decrement)

> 1 The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand. [
>   Note: **the value obtained is a copy of the original value** —end note
>   ]...

Consider the following simple program

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Inside f( x ): x = " << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    std::cout << "Before f( x ): x = " << x << std::endl;
    f(x++);
    std::cout << "After  f( x ): x = " << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Before f( x ): x = 0
Inside f( x ): x = 0
After  f( x ): x = 1
```

Also it will be useful to consider the following simple program

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 0;

void f(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Local (parameter) x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Global variable ::x = " << ::x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f(x++);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Local (parameter) x = 0
Global variable ::x = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The prefix case:

```
return fun(++IteratorBegin, IteratorEnd, f);
```

says, *first* increment `IteratorBegin` by one, and then call the function `fun`. After that, return.

On the other hand, the postfix case:

```
return fun(IteratorBegin++, IteratorEnd, f);
```

says, first call `fun()`, then increment the iterator, and then return.

This means that `fun()` is always being called with the non-incremented iterator.

Answer (score 3):

When you use postfix increment in the tail call, the recursive call does not get the incremented value of the iterator. It gets the value of the iterator before the increment is applied. Hence, the recursion is infinite. That causes stack overflow.